# setter in class won't set variable

Tags: c++, getter-setter

I'm currently trying to make a game in C++. In my code I'm trying to nest my variables so that my main doesn't have a lot of includes. My problem right now though is that the value of my variables in my class aren't changing. Stepping through the code it shows it setting the value, but it doesn't work. Anyone know what's going on? Thank you in advance.

This is what I have so far:

Location.h

```
#ifndef LOCATION_H
#define LOCATION_H

#include <string>

class Location
{
public:
    Location(void);
    Location(std::string name);
    ~Location(void);

    std::string GetName();
    void SetName(std::string value);

private:
    std::string m_Name
};

#endif
```

Location.cpp

```
#include "Location.h"

Location::Location(void): m_Name("") {}

Location::Location(std::string name): m_Name(name) {}

Location::~Location(void)
{
}

std::string Location::GetName()
{return m_Name;}

void Location::SetName(std::string value){m_Name = value;}
```

PlayerStats.h

```
#ifndef PLAYERSTATS_H
#define PLAYERSTATS_H

#include "Location.h"

class PlayerStats
{
public:
    PlayerStats(void);
    ~PlayerStats(void);

    Location GetLocation();
    void SetLocation(Location location);

private:
    Location m_Location;
};

#endif
```

PlayerStats.cpp

```
#include "PlayerStats.h"

PlayerStats::PlayerStats(void): m_Location(Location()) {}

PlayerStats::~PlayerStats(void)
{
}

Location PlayerStats::GetLocation(){return m_Location;}

void PlayerStats::SetLocation(Location location){m_Location = location;}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PlayerStats.h"

using namespace std;

PlayerStats playerStats = PlayerStats();

int main()
{
    playerStats.GetLocation().SetName("Test");
    cout<< playerStats.GetLocation().GetName()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Careful about code dumping here... try to make [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting

Comment: Generally setter methods like that have a signature resembling `void SetName(const std::string& value)`. The constructor should probably follow the same pattern.

Comment: @Conduit Okay I'll reduce it to where the problem is. I'm trying to not code dump. I have very little right now and want to only show where my issue is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that

```
Location GetLocation();
```

returns a copy of the location, so when you call SetName here:

```
playerStats.GetLocation().SetName("Test");
```

You're changing the name of the temporary copy, and the change is lost as soon as the semicolon is hit.

More broadly, this kind of design (nesting classes and nesting includes so that main doesn't have a lot of includes, and using a.b.c() style code to access nested members) isn't great C++ style:

- Having a bunch of source files that (transitively) include a bunch of header files means that changing a single header file will trigger recompilations of a bunch of source files. Compile times can be a significant issue in larger C++ projects, so reducing compile times by controlling #include's is important.  Read up on "forward declarations" for more information.
- Writing code like `a.b.c()` is considered bad object-oriented design, because it reduces encapsulation: not only does the caller have to know about a's details, it has to know about b's also.  Sometimes this is the most expedient way to write code, but it's not something to be blindly done just to reduce #include's.  Read up on "Law of Demeter" for more information.

Comment: Those are some good points. I will have to look at forward declarations then. Can I use that method multiple times in the same class?

I'm having trouble understanding Law of Demeter though. Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork - Yes, you can use forward declarations as many times as you want. The only complicating factor is that member variables can't use forward declarations, because the compiler needs the full class details to lay out memory for a member variable. You can use forward declarations with references, parameters and return types, and pointers (and smart pointers), so replacing a directly included member variable with a smart pointer to a member variable works. For more details, please post a follow-up question; it gets too hard to discuss in comments.

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork - Regarding Demeter, briefly: `main()` already knows about PlayerStats's internals.  If it calls PlayerStats.GetLocation().SetName(), then it knows about Location's internals as well, and encapsulation is weakened.  In this case, it may be okay for main to know about both (it is main, after all), but using code like `a.b.c()` without considering such issues isn't great OO design.  Again, comments aren't a great forum to discuss this; Programmers Stack Exchange probably has better explanations of Demeter already.

Comment: I think I understand forward declaration now so thank you for that. Do you have a link I can use to find information on the Law of Demeter? I can't find any good examples of the law or how to fix my code so it doesn't break the law.

Comment: @WhyYouNoWork - Wikipedia has an article; [this page](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) also looks good. Demeter is a guideline for good OO design, so it's a more advanced topic than forward declarations and pass-by-reference; it'll make more sense as you get more experience with OO.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the result of `playerStats.GetLocation()`, you could make `GetLocation()` pass-by-reference (use ampersand, &, on the return argument).  Otherwise you are just setting values in a temporary copy of `PlayerStats::m_Location`.

Alternatively, you could use the `SetLocation()` function.

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding pass-by-reference. I have had quite a few people try explain them to me, but I still don't understand how they work. How does it work?